# How to make NavMesh Agent stop and then continue his movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

I am trying to make enemy **patrolling system**, where evrytime guard **reaches** his point, he **stopes** for 10 seconds, and then **continue** his movement. I've tried combining animations from **Blend tree with isStopped** property from **NavMeshAgent**.

EDIT: My current script makes agent move to point, then he stopes for some time, and then only walk animation plays, but he staing on one place.

```
public Transform[] points;
private int destPoint = 0;
public NavMeshAgent agent;
public Animator animator;
public int time;

void Start()
{
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    animator = transform.Find("Enemy").GetComponent<Animator>();

    // Disabling auto-braking allows for continuous movement
    // between points (ie, the agent doesn't slow down as it
    // approaches a destination point).
    //agent.autoBraking = false;
}


void GotoNextPoint()
{
    // Returns if no points have been set up
    if (points.Length == 0)
        return;

    // Set the agent to go to the currently selected destination.
    agent.destination = points[destPoint].position;

    // Choose the next point in the array as the destination,
    // cycling to the start if necessary.
    destPoint = (destPoint + 1) % points.Length;
    //agent.speed = 1f;
    //animator.SetFloat("Blend", agent.speed);
}

void Update()
{
    if (agent.remainingDistance == 0f && time == 100000)
    {
        agent.speed = 1f;
        Debug.Log(agent.remainingDistance);
        animator.SetFloat("Blend", 1);
        GotoNextPoint();
    }
    else if (agent.remainingDistance <= 0.5f && agent.remainingDistance != 0f && time == 100000)
    {
        animator.SetFloat("Blend",0);
        agent.enabled = false;
        GotoNextPoint();
    }
    else if(animator.GetFloat("Blend") == 0)
    {
        time--;
    }

    if (time == 99000 && animator.GetFloat("Blend") == 0)
    {
        time = 10000;
        agent.enabled = true;
        agent.isStopped = false;
        animator.SetFloat("Blend", 1);
        agent.autoRepath = true;
        GotoNextPoint();
    }
}
```

I changed few lines of code, now agent moves after first stop, but second time he stops at second poitm,walking animation still working, time doesn't decrementing

```
if (time == 99000 && animator.GetFloat("Blend") == 0)
    {
        time = 10000;
        agent.enabled = true;
        agent.isStopped = false;
        animator.SetFloat("Blend", 1);
        //New lines of code
        agent.ResetPath();
        destPoint = (destPoint + 1) % points.Length;
        agent.SetDestination(points[destPoint].position);
    }[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would use the *"SetDestination"* function in order to set the next destination.

In the end you wrote:

```
if (time == 99000 && animator.GetFloat("Blend") == 0)
{
    time = 10000;  *-> needs to be 100000, not 10000*
    agent.enabled = true;
    agent.isStopped = false;
    animator.SetFloat("Blend", 1);
    agent.autoRepath = true;
    GotoNextPoint();
}
```

You can use *"NavMeshAgent.ResetPath"* to reset the path instead of using *"autoRepath"*.

After the *"ResetPath"*, use the *"SetDestination"* inside the function GotoNextPoint().

One more very important thing - Check that there is more than one point.
If there is just one point, your guard will just walk at the same spot.

For more information, is suggest to check out [Unity NavMeshAgent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.html)

Comment: Thanks, I am gonna try this

Comment: And yeah, I forgot to say, patroling must be infinite

Comment: Oh my god, it works, but not compleatly. After waiting for 10 sceonds - he continued his movement and reached second point, but then he just staing there with walking animation. I made such changes:  instead of using agent.autoRepath = true;
    GotoNextPoint(); I used: agent.ResetPath();
            destPoint = (destPoint + 1) % points.Length;
            agent.SetDestination(points[destPoint].position);

Comment: Did you change the "time=10000" to "time=100000" ?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Simply calling the **NavMeshAgent.ResetPath** was the solution for me. Clears the current path.

When the path is cleared, the agent will not start looking for a new path until SetDestination is called.

Note that if the agent is on an OffMeshLink when this function is called, it will complete the link immediately.

For more details, [check the documentation.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.ResetPath.html)